# Creating a smooth swipe behavior using jQueryMobile which reveals a div

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, swipe

What im trying to do is to reveal some content while sliding to the right/left.
im currently basing my behavior on the simple event "on swipeleft" but that doesn't give me what i intended to.

```
 $("li").on("swipeleft",function(){
        alert("You swiped left!");
    });
```

I want that while doing swipe, the content of the li itself would move to the left and while that is happening a fixed div will be revealed. I hope anyone could suggest me the right way doing this because currentnly, the alert i'm showing, appears only after i finish the swipe and not while i'm doing it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could absolutely position the hidden divs at right and left, and then on swipe animate the left/right margins to reveal the divs:

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/y7Sdu/)**

```
<li><div class="leftFixed">DIV</div><a href="#">Acura</a><div class="rightFixed">DIV</div></li>
```

The CSS:

```
.leftFixed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.rightFixed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li a{
    z-index: 100;
}
```

The swipe event handlers:

```
$("li a").on("swiperight",function(){
    $(this).parents("li").find(".leftFixed").show();
    $(this).parents("li").find(".rightFixed").hide();
    $(this).animate({"margin-left": "60px", "margin-right": "0px"}, 200);
});
$("li a").on("swipeleft",function(){
    $(this).parents("li").find(".leftFixed").hide();
    $(this).parents("li").find(".rightFixed").show();
    $(this).animate({"margin-right": "60px", "margin-left": "0px"}, 200);
});
```

Comment: You got it. I was working on something more complicated.

Comment: Hey @ezanker , Your solution works very well on web! Unfortunately it is not smooth at all on mobile.. If you are experienced with that could u add some inputs about it?

Comment: @Popokoko, possibly the jQuery animate is slow on under-powered devices. You could try CSS transition instead: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/y7Sdu/1/

Comment: hmm, it is not only about smoothness, the swipe works once in a while :/ There must be someone who is experienced with that.

Comment: @Popokoko check this, http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/k58Kh/ it's not made for listview with `data-inset="true"`, maybe Erik can play around, he is good at CSS.

Comment: Thanks! I meant it only works with read-only list items not linked ones.